# Snowflake Float value with 16 precision loaded as exponential

Tags: floating-point, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, precision

Data file has value: 2014050600001253

Float column in Snowflake is loaded with: 2.01405060000125e+15

Is there a way to prevent the exponential format and keep the value as it is in the file with float data type?

File format used:

```
CREATE or Replace FILE FORMAT test_fmt
   TYPE = 'CSV'
   COMPRESSION = 'GZIP'
   FILE_EXTENSION= 'txt'
   FIELD_DELIMITER = '|'
   NULL_IF = ('NULL','null','')
   FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
   DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY'
   TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM'
   EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE;
```

Comment: [snow flake uses IEEE-754 binary64](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html) which has only ~15 digits of precision so obviously you'll only get bogus data if you force it to print 16 digits or more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent the exponential format and keep the value as it is in the file with float data type?

Yes there are ways to force printing the values *without exponential format*, but you can't *keep the value as it is* because Snowflake uses IEEE-754 [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), and such large values when converted to double will be rounded to the closest representable value in double precision. Most of the time the result won't be equal to the original value anymore. For example 20140506000001253 will be printed as 20140506000001252, and 9014050600001253 is also rounded to 9014050600001252

You must use string if you want to store a floating-point value that huge, or if the values are integers smaller than 10<sup>38</sup> then use an integer type

> Precision is approximately 15 digits. For example, for integers, the range is from -9007199254740991 to +9007199254740991 (-2<sup>53</sup> + 1 to +2<sup>53</sup> - 1). Floating-point values can range from approximately 10<sup>-308</sup> to 10<sup>+308</sup>. (More extreme values between approximately 10<sup>-324</sup> and 10<sup>-308</sup> can be represented with less precision.) For more details, see the [Wikipedia article on double-precision numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).
>
> [Numeric Data Types - FLOAT , FLOAT4 , FLOAT8](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#float-float4-float8)

You can

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes that was my mistake. But not all 16-digit numbers can be represented in double

Comment: Note the example 20140506000001252 differs from OP's 2014050600001253 by 10x.  OP is using 16 digits to encode a date/time. float64 good enough until the year 9007.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica in that case using integer is even better since there's no fractional part in the OP's value, and if fractional part is used for the sub-second part then float is even worse

Comment: A wide integer type is _better_, yet for OP's issue here is not of insufficient precision, but of display.  IAC, OP seems content with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

2014050600001253 (a 51-bit value) is exactly representable as a 64-bit floating point type.

"Float column in Snowflake is loaded with: 2.01405060000125e+15" is mistaken, the value is 2.014050600001253e+15.

> Is there a way to prevent the exponential format and keep the value as it is in the file with float data type?

The value in the file is what is is regardless of how your choose to print it.  Print with at least 17 significant decimal digits to get a better idea of its true value.

Even better, since floating point values are encoded with a binary significant, print with a binary/hexadecimal output to avoid decimal artifacts.